# Windows Hex editor to search with Wildcards/Regex in Hex-Mode

Tags: search, editor

I want to search in hex for `00 [01-ff] [01-ff] [01-ff] 00`. I tried the following editors:

- Notepad++ with hex plugin
- HxD
- XVI32
- Far Manager with hex plugin
- 010
- WinMerge

No hex editor allows searching in hex mode with wildcards/regex. Is there any hex editor which has this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend my Hextor ( https://github.com/digitalw0lf/hextor/releases/latest ).
It supports searching for patterns similar to RegExp for binary data, for example:

```
\x00{u8:!0:3}\x00
```

This means:  zero byte; than unsigned 8-bit values, not zero, 3 times; than zero.
You can use arbitrary ranges, like `{float:1.0..1.5}`. See [docs](https://github.com/digitalw0lf/hextor/wiki/Search-and-replace#extended-search-syntax).

Hextor is my pet project, it's freeware.

Comment: Great! This is what I am looking for! Can you please explain your expression in brackets especially the first one? 
u8= ?
:!0 = not zero
:3 = three times

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was wrong. 010 can search in hex mode with wildcards:

```
\x00[\x01-\xff][\x01-\xff][\x01-\xff]\x00
```